# What are the relations between complex numbers and visual representation on $\mathbb{R^2}$?

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, real-numbers, complex-geometry

In a second order polynomial function, the discriminant say how many solution there are e what are their type. Set the discriminant $> 0$, there are two real solutions, which are the points where the parabola touch the $x$-axis. So what is the analog representation when the discriminant $< 0$?

Can complex solutions be represented in $\mathbb{R^2}$?
If not, is there any set, space or something else where the complex solution of a polynomial function has visual representation? Would the set/space be a $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{C}$ set? Since a complex solution has a real part...

Comment: $$x+iy=(x,y)$$
e.g. $$e^{\pi i}=(-1,0)$$

Comment: I suspect your question is asking if there is a way to "see" the complex roots in the ordinary graph in the plane?

Comment: After doing some calculations, my conclusion is that you can with some effort draw the roots, given some reasonable data. But doing so with any precision just isn't worth the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

If the polynomial has real coefficients, then negative discriminant means two complex roots that are conjugates of each other (reflections across the real axis).

If the polynomial has complex coefficients, then it is meaningless to compare the discriminant with zero.